# Format a string and replace %s with html element in scala play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a string like "User: %s" and want to format it and replace "%s" with something like `<a href="#">John</a>`. How should I do it in view files?

P.S. I am using `"User: %s".format("John")` but browser render `I am <a href="#">John</a>` instead of "I am John".

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates#Escaping

Comment: @roby Thank you. Do you want to send it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output raw html in a template:

```
<p>
  @Html(article.content)    
</p>
```

From the [play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates#Escaping)